# Huawei HarmonyOS 3.0.0 can not call reCaptcha Enterprise

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

My problem:
When i update my huawei device to HarmonyOS 3.0.0, i cannot call reCapthca Enterprise successfully, reCaptcha SDK will return error "Missing Feature{name=init, version=3}". Is there any solution to this? :pray

What i expected:

1. I want HarmonyOS 3.0.0 can call reCapthca SDK successfully
2. If HarmonyOS really cannot call the reCaptcha SDK, is there any other way to run reCaptcha on the HarmonyOS? Just want to find a way to let reCaptcha work on HarmonyOS